# Jenkins and its WHEN statement

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

this is very tough to me to understand how Jenkins works. In general when you read documentation and define pipeline, things go smooth. I understand pipelines, stages, steps, scripts. What I don't understand is declaration vs runtime. Especially when it comes to WHEN declaration and evaluating expression. For example:

1. What is the form of expression? Should it return something like: return true; or maybe it should be statement like: true
2. When it gets executed? If I access params.MY_PARAMETER_FROM_INPUT, do WHEN has access to its value picked by user?
3. Is it possible to switch execution between runtime vs pipeline declaration time?
4. Can I ask for stage (input with message box) only if given condition within WHEN is meet and if not, then don't ask for it but run stage anyway?
5. When you use IF from script and when WHEN from stage. Can WHEN be defined else where? Within steps, scripts, pipeline?

For example in a stage I've put `when { expression { params.ENV == 'prod' } } input { message "Really?" ok "Yeah!" }`  but the expression was ignored and the question was always asked (current understanding is that it should skip stage/abort whole pipeline when ENV input param is different than "prod" value)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Using existing semantic of Jenkins I have manage to achieve what I wanted with following snippet:

```
        stage('Confirm if production related') {
            when {
                beforeInput true
                expression { params.ENV == 'production'; }
            }

            input {
                message "Should I deploy to PRODUCTION?"
                ok "Yes, do it!"
            }

            steps {
                script { _ }
            }
        }
```

Not bad but not good either.